# Lighning: is there a way to use Action button to show in related list

Tags: lightning-experience, related-list, action, list-button

Is there a way to show an Action button in the related list of an object in Ligning. The only way I see is to use the "New Button or link" with type "List" selected, but there we can not use the new Lightning action buttons which is not so good.

Only list buttons could be added as related list buttons.
And list buttons that are not JS are actually shown in the lightning related list.

See pictures.

Created test buttons
[image]

Added to the realted list view in the parent object
[image]

Actually visible in Lightning
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Om Prakash

Hi,
For now, I would suggest upvoting this idea which is currently under PRODUCT TEAM REVIEW
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the [https://github.com/jmdohn/Quick-Actions-Everywhere](http://Quick-Actions-Everywhere) by Jeremiah Dohn.

This is a library for pushing quick actions everywhere in Salesforce (except for the global action bar, because, well, they are already everywhere!).

> Supports

- Related List Quick Actions
- Quick Actions in Lightning Pages
- Quick Actions in Community Record Pages and Pages
- Flows in related lists or buttons with redirection
- Quick Actions in Buttons (as opposed to feed)
- Classic, Mobile and of course, Lightning Experience

Comment: I do not feel comfortable putting some github code at a production environment. And when I say Action I do not mean Quick Action.

Comment: What do you mean by action then?

Comment: The ones that you can create from the tab "Buttons, Links, and Actions" on the edit object page. When I read somewhere they sometimes refer to them as quick actions so you have your point. It is just when creating them it says Action and when quick action is mentioned I think more of a app related quick actions.

Comment: I am referring the same. So currently you can have action on Related List of type Create a record and Update a record. If you are trying to add an action of type any other than create or update a record, You cannot add them in related list.

Comment: Please see added pictures and details.  
In the end I see only "List Actions" (created from "New Button or Link") that are not JS actions in the related list in Lightning.